# How can I migrate the existing MVC+AngularJS application to Mvc+Angular4 application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, migration

I have an existing application written in mvc5 and Angular1.I want to convert all Angular1 code to Angular4 code. Is there any tool available for migration/I have to do manually.

Comment: It is 'Angular', not 'Anguler'.

Comment: Thanks for warning the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no such tool available yet.

You have to create it manually. You need to convert all your pages in components as per documentation

These are few document links you can follow though.

https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-convert-an-ionic-1-application-to-ionic-2/

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/migrating-from-angular-1-to-angular-2

https://vsavkin.com/migrating-angular-1-applications-to-angular-2-in-5-simple-steps-40621800a25b